# How a play(java) project, dependent on a specific dll, will run on non windows machine?

Tags: java, windows, playframework

I am starting a Play Framework project which is using a specific **dll** (bought from a company to do some specific operations) loaded with `System.load` command.

My question is: how this will run when I will **deploy** it on cloud?(for instance on cloudbees)?

I understand that locally is working (I am on a windows 7 env. and dlls dependencies can be resolved) but how this will be solved when putting the project in production?

Maybe this questions sounds stupid but I simply don't have the specific knowledge on this area:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For production environments, Play generates a WAR file (a Java Web Application). You have to configure the project in order to include the DLL into this WAR file. Moreover, you have to be sure that the production environment (cloudbees) is Windows based. In other case, it won't work out.